# Unauthorized error 401 using UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a webapp, part of which will allow the user to create a new spreadsheet file in my drive.  The fileURL is a link to an excel file ( download link taken from a file cabinet).

I am struggling with passing authority so that a google spreadsheet can be created.  I am getting an unauthorized error 401.  I had read that having `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` adds the Drive scope, but I am going wrong somewhere.

```
function downloadFile(fileURL, folder) {
  var filename = fileURL.match(".+/(.+?)([\?#;].*)?$")[1];
  var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = {"authorization": "Bearer " + auth};
  var params = { 'method':'post', 'headers':header, 'muteHttpExceptions':true};

  var holder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, params);
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  var blob = response.getBlob();

//delete file if it already exists
  var fileList = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  while (fileList.hasNext()) {
    var fileId = fileList.next().getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
  }

  var resource = {
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "parents": [{id: folder}],
    "title": filename
  }
//Create file
  var res = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob); //put
}
```

Comment: Your script needs to be authorized before you are going to be able to access user information https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Comment: I have the script published as a webapp and set to execute as me.  I allowed the authorisation when I first deployed the webapp.  Do I need to reapply authorisation with each new version?

Comment: you are going to need to authorize it every time you run it probably

Comment: I made a copy of the webapp, ensured the correct resources were set and accepted the authorise request.  Same error.

Comment: I think I was looking at the wrong authorization.  The scopes seem to be okay, but I hadn't passed the ClientID to allow access to my Drive. Didn't think I had to as when the site is available to all, the code will amend a file on my drive; but when permissions are restricted it doesn't.  I think i need to look at gapi.load and gapi.client.init